# quantstrat::apply.paramset error: attempt to select less than one element

Tags: quantstrat

I modified quantstrat demo bee and tried to run optimization on indicator parameters. However, I have tried to simplify optimization as much as I can, but I still got the same error as following:

```
error calling combine function:
<simpleError in fun(result.1, result.2, result.3, result.4, result.5, result.6,     result.7, result.8, result.9, result.10): attempt to select less than one element>
Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds
```

my `sessionInfo` output:

```
R version 3.2.4 (2016-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.4 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils    
[6] datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] doMC_1.3.4                   
 [2] iterators_1.0.8              
 [3] lubridate_1.5.0              
 [4] dplyr_0.4.3                  
 [5] quantstrat_0.9.1739          
 [6] foreach_1.4.3                
 [7] blotter_0.9.1741             
 [8] PerformanceAnalytics_1.4.4000
 [9] FinancialInstrument_1.2.0    
[10] quantmod_0.4-5               
[11] TTR_0.23-1                   
[12] xts_0.9-7                    
[13] zoo_1.7-12                   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.3       magrittr_1.5     
 [3] lattice_0.20-33   R6_2.1.2         
 [5] stringr_1.0.0     tools_3.2.4      
 [7] grid_3.2.4        DBI_0.3.1        
 [9] htmltools_0.3     yaml_2.1.13      
[11] lazyeval_0.1.10   assertthat_0.1   
[13] digest_0.6.9      codetools_0.2-14 
[15] rsconnect_0.4.1.4 rmarkdown_0.9.5  
[17] stringi_1.0-1     compiler_3.2.4
```

Here is my code and data is to be download from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2anjmvmzkm8nt01/CYB_DAY.csv?dl=0). Could anyone help me to figure out where goes wrong? thanks

```
#################################################################### 
#### Load packages 
#####################################################################
library(dplyr)
suppressMessages(require(quantstrat))



####################################################################
#### remove objects 
########################################################################

rm(list = ls(all.names = T))

if(!exists(".instrument")) .instrument <<- new.env()
if(!exists(".blotter")) .blotter <<- new.env()
if(!exists(".strategy")) .strategy <- new.env()



########################################################################
#### DEFINE VARIABLES or parameters 
########################################################################

initDate      = "2000-01-01"
symbol.st     = 'CYB_DAY'
portf.st      = 'bug'
acct.st       = 'colony'
strat.st      = 'bee'
initEq        = 100000
nFast         = 10
nSlow         = 30
nSd           = 1

########################################################################
#### GET DATA
###############################################################
# set your working directory where the data is stored
setwd("/Users/Natsume/Documents/data_exploration_r/data")

currency('USD') # initiate currency
stock(symbol.st ,currency='USD', multiplier=1) # initiate stock

getSymbols(Symbols = symbol.st, src = "csv")


initPortf(
    portf.st, 
    symbol.st, 
    initDate=initDate) # initiate portfolio

initAcct(
    acct.st, 
    portf.st, 
    initEq=initEq, 
    initDate=initDate) # initiate account

initOrders(
    portf.st, 
    initDate=initDate ) # initiate order_book

bee = strategy(strat.st) # create strategy object



addPosLimit(
    portfolio=portf.st,
    symbol=symbol.st, 
    timestamp=initDate,  
    maxpos=300, longlevels = 3) # only trade in one direction once 


bee <- add.indicator( 
    strategy  = strat.st, 
    name      = 'BBands', # TA name
    arguments = list(HLC=quote(HLC(mktdata)), 
                     n=nSlow, 
                     sd=nSd),
    label     = 'BBand')

#### SMA column
bee <- add.indicator(
    strategy  = strat.st, 
    name      = 'SMA', # TA name
    arguments = list(x=quote(Cl(mktdata)), 
                     n=nFast),
    label     = 'MA' )



bee <- add.signal(
    strategy  = strat.st,
    name      = 'sigCrossover',
    arguments = list(columns=c('MA','dn'), 
                     relationship='lt'),
    label     = 'MA.lt.dn')

#### SMA cross over upperBand
bee <- add.signal(
    strategy  = strat.st,
    name      = 'sigCrossover',
    arguments = list(columns=c('MA','up'),
                     relationship='gt'),
    label     = 'MA.gt.up')



bee <- add.rule(
    strategy  = strat.st,
    name      = 'ruleSignal',
    arguments = list(sigcol    = 'MA.gt.up',
                     sigval    = TRUE,
                     replace    = F,
                     orderqty  = 100,
                     ordertype = 'market',  
                     # one of "market","limit","stoplimit", "stoptrailing", or "iceberg" 
                     orderside = 'long',
                     osFUN     = 'osMaxPos'), 

    type      = 'enter',
    label     = 'EnterLONG')

#### exitLong when SMA cross under LowerBand
bee <- add.rule(
    strategy  = strat.st,
    name      = 'ruleSignal',
    arguments = list(sigcol    = 'MA.lt.dn',
                     sigval    = TRUE,
                     replace    = F,
                     orderqty  = 'all',
                     ordertype = 'market',
                     orderside = 'long'),
    type      = 'exit',
    label     = 'ExitLONG')

#### enterShort when SMA cross under LowerBand
bee <- add.rule(
    strategy  = strat.st,
    name      = 'ruleSignal',
    arguments = list(sigcol     = 'MA.lt.dn',
                     sigval    = TRUE,
                     replace    = F,
                     orderqty  =  -100,
                     ordertype = 'market',
                     orderside = 'short',
                     osFUN     = 'osMaxPos'), 
    type      = 'enter',
    label     = 'EnterSHORT')

#### exitShort when SMA cross over upperBand
bee <- add.rule(
    strategy  = strat.st,
    name      = 'ruleSignal',
    arguments = list(sigcol     = 'MA.gt.up',
                     sigval     = TRUE,
                     replace    = F,
                     orderqty   = 'all',
                     ordertype  = 'market',
                     orderside  = 'short'),
    type      = 'exit',
    label     = 'ExitSHORT')




applyStrategy(
    strat.st, 
    portf.st, 
    prefer='Open', # why prefer='Open'
    verbose=T)

updatePortf(
    portf.st) #, 

updateAcct(
    acct.st) # , 

updateEndEq(
    Account = acct.st)#,



### User Set up pf parameter ranges to test
.nFastList = 5:13
.nSlowList  = 10:40
.nSdList = 1:3

# number of random samples of the parameter distribution to use for random run
.nsamples = 10 

add.distribution(strat.st,
                 paramset.label = 'SMA_BBparams',
                 component.type = 'indicator',
                 component.label = 'BBand', #this is the label given to the indicator in the strat
                 variable = list(n = .nSlowList),
                 label = 'BBandMA'
)

add.distribution(strat.st,
                 paramset.label = 'SMA_BBparams',
                 component.type = 'indicator',
                 component.label = 'BBand', #this is the label given to the indicator in the strat
                 variable = list(sd = .nSdList),
                 label = 'BBandSD'
)


add.distribution(strat.st,
                 paramset.label = 'SMA_BBparams',
                 component.type = 'indicator',
                 component.label = 'MA', #this is the label given to the indicator in the strat
                 variable = list(n = .nFastList),
                 label = 'MAn'
)



add.distribution.constraint(strat.st,
                            paramset.label = 'SMA_BBparams',
                            distribution.label.1 = 'BBandMA',
                            distribution.label.2 = 'MAn',
                            operator = '>',
                            label = 'BBandMA>MAn'
)



### parallel computing to speed up

if( Sys.info()['sysname'] == "Windows" )
{
    library(doParallel)
    #  registerDoParallel(cores=detectCores())
    registerDoSEQ()
} else {
    library(doMC)
    registerDoMC(cores=detectCores())
}


results <- apply.paramset(strat.st, 
                          paramset.label='SMA_BBparams', 
                          portfolio.st=portf.st, 
                          account.st=acct.st, 
                          nsamples= .nsamples, # take all options
                          #.nsamples,  only take 10 samples
                          verbose=TRUE)





results$tradeStats %>% View()
```